# Focus after different types of clicking

Tags: android, google-tv

I have two activities. I start second activity by using button in first activity. In second activity I have a focusable element to wich I doing request focus, after second activity starts.

Such problem: If I clicking on button in first activity using enter/ok button, the focusable element in second acivity focuses, but if I click on button in first activity on left mouse click button, the focusable element in second activity doesn't focuses.

If anybody knows what is this, help me please. Any ideas whill be helpfull. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Setting to focusable item in my second activity: android:focusableInTouchMode="true" - solved my problem